# Как в javascript добавить класс кликнутому элементу? Аналог $(this) из jQuery

Tags: javascript

Как добавить класс кликнутому элементу?

Если делать так:

```js
let li = document.querySelector('.li');
li.addEventListener("click", function() {
  li.classList.add("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="text">Цифры</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="text">Заглавные буквы</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="text">Строчные буквы</div>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <div class="checkbox"></div>
    <div class="text">Спец. символы: ! @ # $ % ^ & * ( ) - _ + = ; : , . / ? \ | ` ~ [ ] { }</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

то отрабатывает только клик по первому элементу. Есть ли аналог $(this) из jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function liClickHandler(e) {
  this.classList.add("active");
}
let li = document.querySelectorAll('.li').forEach(item => 
  item.addEventListener("click", liClickHandler)
);
```

Comment: подскажите, а как удалить класс, кликнув по тому же элементу? tpggleClass в jQuery

Comment: @Frontender `classList.contains`, `classList.remove`, `classList.toggle` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: @Frontender, если нужен аналог `$.fn.toggleClass`, а не `$(this)`, то это надо было изначально указать *в вопросе*.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//let li = document.querySelector('.li');   получает только первый элемент из массива, так то в данном случае не подходит

// для захвата всех элементов надо использовать  document.querySelectorAll

let li = document.querySelectorAll('.li');

for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) { //далее прокручиваем в цикле 
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() { // при клике 
    if (!this.classList.contains('active')) { // проверяем есть ли у элемента, на котором произошло событие, class "active"
      for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        li[i].classList.remove("active"); // а тут удаляем тупо у всех
      }
      this.classList.add("active"); //если нет, добавляем
      console.log("this - ADD");
    } else {
      this.classList.remove("active"); // если есть, удаляем
      console.log("this - remove");
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li"> Li - 1</li>
  <li class="li"> Li - 2</li>
  <li class="li"> Li - 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

У [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) есть метод `toggle`, это то, что Вы ищите:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.li')
        .forEach(li => li.onclick = () => li.classList.toggle("active"));
```

```css
.active {
  background:wheat;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li">111</li>
  <li class="li">222</li>
  <li class="li">333</li>
</ul>
```